# how to put image_tag with link_to_unless_current in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like put "image_tag" instead of "en"

> <%= link_to_unless_current "en", locale: "en"%>

i try this one but it's not working:

> <%= link_to_unless_current "#{image_tag('flag.png')}", locale: "en" %>

Thank for the answers.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: when i want change the language i click on "en".but i would like to change "en" by the images.(image_flag).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
<%= link_to_unless_current image_tag('flag.png'), locale: "en" %>
```